# auto SQL field's quotation marks by type in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, quotes

Suppose that I want to create an SQL SELECT statement dynamically with reflection on primary key. I search in the table for primary keys and then, I make the statement.

Problem is, I don't know the type of fields that compose the primary key before getting them. So, if it's a string or date, I must add quotation marks but not if it's an int.

Atm, I am doing like that :

```
var type = field.GetType().Name;
if (type.ToLower().StartsWith("string") || type.ToLower().StartsWith("date"))
{
    field = "\"" + field + "\"";
} else if (type.ToLower().StartsWith("char"))
{
    field = "\'" + field + "\'";
}
```

With this code, I can handle some SQL types but there are a lot more.

My problem is that it's combined with LinQ. I got a DataContext object and a generic type table from the context. And context.ExecuteQuery only allows parameters to be passed has values. I also tried with Dynamic LinQ but I got the same problem

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is simply the wrong way to write SQL. Parameterize it and all these problems evaporate (as do problems with "which date format to use", etc. And of course the biggie: SQL injection.

Then it just becomes a case of adding `@whatever` into the TSQL, and using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("whatever", field)` (or similar).

---

Update (from comments): since you mention you are using `DataContext.ExecuteQuery`, this becomes easier: that method is fully parameterized using the `string.Format` convention, i.e.

```
object field = ...;
var obj = db.ExecuteQuery<SomeType>(
      "select * from SomeTable where Id = {0}", field).ToList(); // or Single etc
```

No string conversions necessary.

(the last parameter is a `params object[]`, so you can either pass multiple discreet terms, or you can populate an `object[]` and pass that, if the number of terms is not fixed at compile-time; each term in the array maps by (zero-based) index to the `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`... etc token in the query)

Comment: My problem is that it's combined with LinQ. I got a `DataContext` object and a generic type table from the context. And `context.ExecuteQuery` only allows parameters to be passed has values. I also tried with Dynamic LinQ but I got the same problem

Comment: @RonanLamour `ExecuteQuery` is parameterized - I will edit - 2 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with parameters? For instance if you are using SQLServer as a database and you want to do this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id = " + field;
```

Then you should use sometething like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id = @field"
```

and add parameter to your command:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@field", field);
command.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

EDIT: Watch out that for different database providers the syntax for the SQL query is different, the same for the Access would be

```
"SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id = ?";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("field", field);
```

Comment: My problem is that it's combined with LinQ. I got a DataContext object and a generic type table from the context. And context.ExecuteQuery only allows parameters to be passed has values. I also tried with Dynamic LinQ but I got the same problem